# Stack Exchange is intermittently failing at random areas

Tags: bug, status-completed, outage

Stack Exchange is intermittently failing at random areas.

Some issues experienced by me and others:

- I got logged out and couldn't log in
- Stack Overflow intermittently goes down saying it's unavailable
- Search is broken everywhere
- Posting was broken at some point/is still broken now

Comment: I had an issue posing an edit at Ask Ubuntu (about 20 mins ago), it timed out three times, with a generic "Edit could not be submitted" message. Though it seems OK now. I guess that is related.

Comment: I am getting the first three issues.  What's going on, y'all?

Comment: I'm getting unusual slowness at times... particularly when searching, it just hangs...

Comment: It's definitely network-wide.

Comment: I'm getting the message "We are currently offline for maintenance" when trying to search. But according to the twitter status - https://twitter.com/StackStatus - and the blog there is no planned maintenance and no messages posted.

Comment: Conveying a message from Nick: "We are seeing some abnormal search traffic we're investigating and working to resolve any disruptions still present."

Comment: There is a problem at SO, about [questions posting twice](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/400123/questions-are-posting-twice), that started an hour ago; nothing about the Search. --- I confirm the search bug, in North America. --- As of a second ago search works, fast. --- and broken again. :(

Comment: @Rob the double posting is related to the search outage. See the comment I left there.

Comment: Things should be getting back to normal now.

Comment: @Catija yes, it works okay now.

Comment: @Catija, unfortunately  the author deleted their post, so I can't see the comment you left there. Good thing I mentioned it, if it's related, because it was reported prior to this report above.

Comment: This was only posted three minutes later, so they're not really different, @Rob :) and Journeyman Geek's question was actually posted first.

Comment: [Search has been re-enabled across the Stack Exchange network. Apologies for the interruption.](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/1292101436319379456) - Nick Craver

Comment: Stuff being fixed is not a no repro!!! If you want an explanation... kinda needs to be open.

Comment: Yes people. Don't we want the juicy juicy after action reports? ._.

Comment: @Catija totally agree. In theory, any bug that was ever fixed can't be "reproduced" anymore, because, well, it won't happen anymore. So using this close reason for bugs that were fixed is totally wrong, and whenever I see this misused this way, I consider starting feature request to just remove this close reason or make it more clear when it should be used. (And when it should not be used)

Comment: @JourneymanGeek looks like no details at all this time. :(